# Approximate the age of the employees with an histogram

Tags: statistics, estimation

[image]

The following histogram represents the age distribution of employees of a textile company. (The absence of gradation on the vertical axis is intentional)

1. knowing that 225 employees are under 45, there are fewer than 505 employees in the factory.
2. The approximate average age of employees is greater than 46.

Which are true?

I have no clue how to say which one is true. How can I deal with this question?

**EDIT**

Intuitively, I think only the number 2 is true. That question is hard for me.

Comment: Hint: As we always do with unknowns: give them a name. Call them $x$. Let $x$ be the height of one notch on the vertical axis. Now the numbers of people represented by successive bars is: $2x, 2x, 5x, 6x, 4x, x$. Use the given conditions and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expected to extend the ticks on the vertical axis through the bars.  Each rectangle will then represent the same number of employees. There are $9$ rectangles below age $45$ and $11$ above, so $20$ total rectangles.  Each rectangle represents $25$ employees.  That says there are $500$ total employees.  1 is true.

It could be that all the employees in a rectangle are at the minimum age for that rectangle.  I didn't do the arithmetic, but I am sure the average age would then come out below $46$.  This would say that 2 could be false.

Comment: So only 1 is true, right?

Comment: Only 1 is known to be true.  Did you read the answer, particularly the last sentence of each paragraph?